# Why do we create object variables like this?

Tags: java

I am new to learning Java, and I was told to create object variables like this:

```
Integer a = new Integer(2);
```

Instead of like this:

```
Integer a = 2;
```

Can someone explain why is creating object variables the 2nd way bad?
edit: I am adding this here cause I am getting mixed answers
Which one am I supposed to use and when?

Comment: Who says the 2nd way is bad? Do you have any reference for that.

Comment: Well, the question is whether it is about creating objects or about the special case of `Integer`. `Integer`s between -128 and 127 inclusive are required to be cached, so with `Integer a = 2` you're not always creating an object.

Comment: The new keyword instantiates a new object of the given type. The assignment of two for an integer only works because it's automatically boxed.

Comment: These two do roughly the same thing.  But the second is better IMO, because it is easier to type, is more readable, and also has the benefit @arshajii states in his answer (which I don't understand why was downvoted)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but since you say you're new to Java, you may be confused. In most cases you shouldn't create an `Integer` object at all, but rather use the **primitive type** `int` (i.e., `int a = 2;`).

Comment: No one said to me that the 2nd way is bad, but had an experience where it was giving me errors, because i was using the 2nd way. I don't remember what was i doing when it happened so don't ask me for the code.

I use this when i need an object for object methods or when a method returns an Integer.

Answer (score 2):

**The second approach is actually better**, since it will implicitly call [`Integer.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)). From the docs:

> Returns an Integer instance representing the specified `int` value. If a new `Integer` instance is not required, **this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor `Integer(int)`, as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values**. This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

(Emphasis mine.)

See also: [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: Thanks for the emphasis, I was confused how to do them

Could you make the explanation easier cause I don't think I understand what you mean

Comment: You're lacking a source. And that's something which really bothers me.

Comment: @maio290 The source is linked...

Comment: No, the source doesn't give the info WHY this is done. This is found here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html ...

Comment: @maio290 While that's certainly important, I really don't think it's directly relevant to the question. The source clearly describes why this alternative is better, which is ultimately the point of the question. In any case I can reference that link as well.

Comment: As of *Java 9*, the `Integer(int val)` constructor is deprecated.